# what happened to array variable that is not initialized?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[3]={1,2,3};
    printf("%d",a[4]);
}
```

The output of this program is 0 even if I haven't initialized a[4]. As an array which is initialized, I should get an error if i try to it.

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: The problem of `a[4]` is not it's uninitialized. It's outside the bound of the array.

Comment: Accessing a position out of bounds for an array is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading beyond the end of the array. It just happens to have a value of zero. What happens when you do this is undefined by the c language. Your compiler and runtime can do anything they want in this case, including returning 0 or giving you an error.

Answer (score 1):

In single line: the result will be **indeterminate**.

#### 6.7.9 Initialization (p10):

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
> **indeterminate**.

#### 3.19.2: indeterminate value

> either an unspecified value or a trap representation